# SQL only stores the last element/Json object into database

Tags: php, json

Trying to grab data from an API, and store in a database. But element/object of an array is stored in the database.
Any help on how to get all the data stored in the database would be appreciated.
My php code:

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
//print_r($data);

//get the employee details
foreach ($data['players'] as $myp) {
    $name = $myp['name'];
    $posi = $myp['position'];
    $nation = $myp['nationality'];
    $market = $myp['marketValue'];

//insert into mysql table
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db); //database and connection 

$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s'); //date stamp formatting
//sql query that insert the user info into the database
$sql =  "INSERT INTO staffdb ( Name, Position, Nationality, Market, Created)       
        VALUES('$name', '$posi', '$nation', '$market', '$date')";
}
//if the connection is sucessful, display regards message
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Thank you <br/>";
} else {   //if the connection is not established
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_close($conn); //close of process or connection
```

The api looks like this:

```
"players": [

    {
        "name": "Marcos Alonso",
        "position": "Left-Back",
        "jerseyNumber": 3,
        "dateOfBirth": "1990-12-28",
        "nationality": "Spain",
        "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
        "marketValue": "9,000,000 €"
    },
    {
        "name": "Marco van Ginkel",
        "position": "Central Midfield",
        "jerseyNumber": null,
        "dateOfBirth": "1992-12-01",
        "nationality": "Netherlands",
        "contractUntil": "2018-06-30",
        "marketValue": "7,000,000 €"
    },
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: the closing `}` of foreach is some rows to high. Needs to be _after_ mysqli_query

Comment: but you should get `mysqli_connect` out of that loop

Comment: ..I ment `mysqli_select_db`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I moved the closing } as you said but only the first 4 elements that are add. Kan you help me on how to get every element stored? Also after i moved the mysqli_select_db to either above or below the foreach, it gave error: Thank you
Thank you
Thank you
Thank you
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Golo Kanté', 'Defensive Midfield', 'France', '30,000,000 €', '2017-04-0' at line 2. Am pretty new in php, kan you help me thanks..